# jQuery tabs style right indenting loaded content

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, margins

jQuery tabs are adding a margin of about 25px to the left of my loaded content. this seems to be a default behavior, as the space on my page looks similar to the space on the   ui example site. any ideas about how to go about adjusting it inside the jQuery-ui stylesheet without breaking anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding comes from this rule: `.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel`, it's default value is `padding: 1em 1.4em;`. You could either change it directly in the jQuery UI CSS file or override it in your own CSS file.

Since the style applies directly to a the tab panel itself this shouldn't break anything else.

Comment: i eventually realized i was only using the tabs because of the ajax option, i've been trying to tangle with the ajax more directly since then.